# Need sugestion to accuire a job in data mining

Tags: data-mining, beginner

I interested in data mining specialization and have been enrolled in data mining specialization course at Coursera by University of Illinois. This specialization course contains four parts. The very first course is "Data Visualization" which contains more conceptual knowledge rather than technical skills that not as expected.

Anybody can give me suggestion what can I expect after completed that course in the case to find a job in data mining specialization?

If I am intended to acquire engineering job, is this course right for me?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the site! The course you are taking sounds like a good start; but I am not sure if it will be enough to land you a job as a Data Engineer (depending on your other qualifications, of course).
If you are willing to invest more time, [here is a great text on how to learn Data Science in one hundred hours](https://www.quora.com/What-should-I-learn-in-data-science-in-100-hours-I-am-free-for-the-next-10-days-and-would-like-to-learn-whatever-I-can-in-the-next-10-days-and-I-can-put-in-10-hours-a-day-What-can-I-learn-to-get-a-hang-of-it-and-get-started?share=cad63442&srid=hRRiT).

Comment: Thank your for response.
I may have not so many time to be invested, but after read Trusov's answer in the link you provided, I might do some hack to learn Scikit (I have already familiar with basic MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

I like coursera and there are many data science programs to choose from. If I were you, I would look into the 10-course series certificate that is offered by John Hopkins. You will come out of that course being pretty good with R and establishing a good base of knowledge for the rest of your growth as a data scientist.

Comment: Thank you for nice answer. I have look a course which you mentioned, before taken a course by Illinois. I think that course not to be consideration, since I am not good enough at statistics.

Comment: @HafidzJazuliLuthfi You can always take statistics as a separate course. Try to find a course in Applied Statistics and you should be fine with 1 class. Just try and learn as much as you can about distributions, hypothesis testing, z-test, t-test and that should give you a good base to work from for a career in data science.

Comment: Thank you @Unkown Coder,
I have already enrolled statistics course on udacity. It's good course i think, since included Anova method in the last chapter.